# Is there a way in PowerShell that I can find all files in a directory?

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
Write-S3Object `
   -BucketName "abilitest-user-staging" `
   -Key  "content/bundles/$filename" `
   -File "content/bundles/$filename" `
   -HeaderCollection @{"Cache-Control" = "public,max-age=1200"}
```

Is there a way that I could make PowerShell loop through all the files in the content/bundles directory and repeatedly execute this code with the name of each file substituted in where I now have $filename?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem $path | ForEach-object{Write-S3OBject .... -File $_.FullName...}`? Unless I am missing something I don't know what is complicated about this one. Sounds like a dup to me.

Comment: @Matt - I see you are using $.FullName.  Is that the filename or the filename and the path? What I would like is just the filename and to be able to specify content/bundles as the start directory relative to the directory where the script is run.

Comment: `Fullname` is the full path. `Name` is just the file name and extension

Comment: Try to write some code to do what you want and we'll correct you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem c:\somefolder -Recurse | 
   Foreach-Object{
     Write-Host $_.FullName;
     # Do more code here with each item
   }
```